# Storing Scripts vs Storing Symbolic Links in /usr/local/bin

Tags: bash, filesystem, symbolic-link

I have a bunch of scripts that I use on a regular basis. I am storing them in a folder on my disk(not in the `$PATH`),so I had to manually execute them from that folder. I (finally) decided to make my life easier and move all of my scripts into the `/usr/local/bin`. The question is, should I move my files directly, or should I simply create symbolic links pointing to the files? Is there are any caveats I have to keep in mind while making a decision?

Comment: Why not add your current script path to PATH ?

Comment: I use both.   On files (scripts) I'm going to edit frequently, I store in my $HOME folder and have links to them in /usr/local/bin/.   For scripts that are generic, they will be copied directly to /usr/local/bin (a script I have for new installs puts them there as that directory gets wiped on re-install even with no-format installs I believe).

Comment: @SorenA I want to add only certain files from the folder, not the whole folder. I could obviously make a subfolder and add it to the `$PATH` but I want to do it differently

Comment: @guiverc if you do it this way, it becomes complicated to always remember which script is physically there and which is a symlink, isn't it? If you want to delete certain things at some point it will probably be a nightmare to sort things out. You could use `ls -l` to check it, of course, but it will still take some time

Comment: Follow whatever standards your organization has, the setup is describe is my own where I expect scripts located in /usr/local/bin/ as placed there by a post-install script run on a new box. The only local files (replacing the default) are scripts I regularly edit/change specific to a box & they'll be local.  For some boxes only $HOME is backed up (so modified local scripts get saved but those in /usr/local/bin/ won't be; no need as a re-install will have them re-populated by post-install script).. My use fits how I use it, doesn't mean it'll work for others.

Comment: @guiverc Sure, I wasn't saying that your setup is bad. Even if I am not going to use it the  opinion of a more experienced user is always appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you store the executable themselves or a symbolic link to them in `/usr/local/bin` is essentially just a matter of your personal preference. If it were me, I would probably work with symbolic links to the actual files in a folder under my Documents folder. That way, 1) I would be able to edit them without needing to be root, and 2) they would be safeguarded anytime along with my backup of the Documents folder.

If you are the only one using your scripts, it may be more convenient to store your scripts in `~/.local/share/bin` or in `~/bin` in your home folder. In Ubuntu, both of these folders are automatically added to your PATH if they exist. Advantages: 1) you do not need to be root to change/update scripts 2) you are the only user having access to them.

If other users need also access to the scripts, `/usr/local/bin` is the perfect location for that. That folder is not used/managed by the operating system. It is specifically there for your custom home made scripts.

Using these folders prevents the need of having to change the PATH environment yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You actually raised an important point of being able to edit scripts directly added to `/usr/local/bin` only with `sudo`. I didn't even think about that